# Make an array of words in alphabetical order in java, after reading them from a file

Tags: java, arrays, file

I've got the following code that opens and read a file and separates it to words.
My problem is at making an array of these words in alphabetical order.

```
import java.io.*;

class MyMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File file = new File("C:\\Kennedy.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file)));
        String line = null;
        int line_count=0;
        int byte_count;
        int total_byte_count=0;
        int fromIndex;
        while( (line = br.readLine())!= null ){
            line_count++;
            fromIndex=0;
            String [] tokens = line.split(",\\s+|\\s*\\\"\\s*|\\s+|\\.\\s*|\\s*\\:\\s*");
            String line_rest=line;
            for (int i=1; i <= tokens.length; i++) {
                byte_count = line_rest.indexOf(tokens[i-1]);
                //if ( tokens[i-1].length() != 0)
                //System.out.println("\n(line:" + line_count + ", word:" + i + ", start_byte:" + (total_byte_count + fromIndex) + "' word_length:" + tokens[i-1].length() + ") = " + tokens[i-1]);
                fromIndex = fromIndex + byte_count + 1 + tokens[i-1].length();
                if (fromIndex < line.length())
                    line_rest = line.substring(fromIndex);
            }
            total_byte_count += fromIndex;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How does your file look?

Comment: You should consider using a `List`, and then you can just call `Collections.sort(list)`.

Comment: @dinomario10 you mean instead of the array tokens?

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis It is a text with letters and symbols .

Comment: Well, but sample input is important..

Comment: Do you want to sort the words in one line, or across all lines? Do you want to allow duplicates?

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis Here is the first line for example:
Vice President Johnson, Mr. Speaker, Mr. Chief Justice,

Comment: Yes, consider having a `List<String> listOfWords`. Just do `listOfWords = Arrays.asList(tokens);` and then sort them. (`Collections.sort(...)`) sorts strings alphabetically.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I want to sort the words from the whole txt file in an ADT . I don't want to allow duplicates...

Comment: Then you can use a `LinkedHashSet`. After sorting strings alphabetically in a `List`, dump them to a `LinkedHashSet` constructor.

Comment: Use a `TreeSet<String>`

Answer (score 1):

I would read the `File` with a [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)<sup>1</sup> (and I would prefer the [`File(String,String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) constructor to provide the *parent folder*). And, you should remember to `close` your resources explicitly in a `finally` block *or* you might use a [`try-with-resources` statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html). Finally, for *sorting* you can store your **words** in a [`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) in which *the elements are ordered using their [natural ordering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)*<sup>2</sup>. Something like,

```
File file = new File("C:/", "Kennedy.txt");
try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file)) {
    Set<String> words = new TreeSet<>();
    int line_count = 0;
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        line_count++;
        String[] tokens = line.split(",\\s+|\\s*\\\"\\s*|\\s+|\\.\\s*|\\s*\\:\\s*");
        Stream.of(tokens).forEach(word -> words.add(word));
    }
    System.out.printf("The file contains %d lines, and in alphabetical order [%s]%n",
            line_count, words);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

<sup>1<sub>Mainly because it requires less code.</sub></sup>
<sup>2<sub>*or by a [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) provided at set creation time*</sub></sup>

Comment: @KaterinaTsellou The above is using Java 8+ lambdas. If you are on an earlier (EOL) version of Java, you can use a `for-each` loop. Otherwise, please *explain* the error you're getting.

Comment: An anonymous class cannot subclass the final class Scanner

Comment: This code doesn't subclass `Scanner`. What version of Java are you using? And what version is your IDE compliance level set to?

Comment: I'm using the eclipse platform

Comment: Window > Preferences > Java > Compiler: "Compiler Compliance Level"

Comment: compliance level 6.0

Comment: Set it to 8 to use the code here, **Java 7** has been EOL since April of last year.

Answer (score 0):

If you are storing the tokens in a String Array, use Arrays.sort() and get a naturally sorted Array. In this case as its String, you will get a sorted array of tokens.